# Ionic.zip extraction failing - DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

I'm trying to extract a zip file using [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). Whenever I try to extract an existing zip file with a path, I get a DirectoryNotFoundException. The path I am passing in gets changed for some reason, causing the DirectoryNotFoundException. I'm following the examples found [here](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples).

Here is my code:

```
    string zipToUnpack = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\data.zip";
    string TmpDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Temp";
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
    {
        zip.ExtractAll(TmpDirectory, true);
    }
```

The DirectoryNotFoundException shows me the path it is looking in and it isn't TmpDirectory. Instead, it's TmpDirectory + another location in my ProgramFiles directory.

Comment: Does the code have permission to write to that directory?

Comment: Just posted my answer - seems to be related to my Powershell-created zip, and not the code.